# What device is this?

Tags: hardware

I've seen a particular phone on Engadget and many other sites but I can't figure out what it actually is.

Here is a link: https://www.engadget.com/2016/05/22/google-science-journal-for-android/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about the one in the title picture, it's obviously an **LG V10**, specifically the dark blue color variant. The signature "secondary screen" is present.